# Access Write Violation When Accessing the Value of a Register in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, access-violation, masm, cpu-registers

```
compare PROTO, p1:DWORD, p2:DWORD
.code
compare proc p1:DWORD, p2:DWORD
    mov eax, p1
    mov edx, p2
    mov eax, [eax] ;Getting an access violation here
    mov edx, [edx] ; Would probably get one here too, why?
    sub eax, edx
    ret
compare endp
main PROC
     LOCAL thesize:DWORD
    mov thesize, 3
    mov fill, 5
    INVOKE compare, thesize, thesize

    ret
main ENDP
```

Hey guys, just curious as to why this code isn't working? What's an alternative way to make it work, I'm just playing around with registers and was trying some similar code when filling an array, but I got stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not accessing value of a register but trying to access an invalid memory address. [eax] is a memory access via eds:eax or so. And eax register in your case contains an incorrect offset within data segment pointing to an incorrect page in memory.

Comment: @AlexanderVX how do I modify the value at that location in memory then? Basically, I want to be modifying p1 and p2 permanently, but without directly moving a value into those variables.

Comment: You can only modify the value at some address when you have correct address. The intent of your code is not clear. I guess Gunner's answer is closer to what you want but I see just plain errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing, but since it looks like you want dereference a mem address, you must use `addr` for local vars to get/pass that address.

```
main PROC
     LOCAL thesize:DWORD
    mov thesize, 3

;    INVOKE compare, thesize, thesize
;    same as:
;    push    3
;    push    3
;    call    compare

    ; this is what you want:
    invoke compare, addr thesize, addr thesize
;    same as:
;    lea     eax, thesize
;    push    eax
;    push    eax
;    call    compare
    ret
main ENDP
```